# gray line between div's in firefox on linux mint

Tags: css

I really don't have an idea what is happening.
The gray line is at the end of the image, it's not even the line break between the div's. it's only in firefox.

The website is : http://buzzmarket.co.il/tickets/

screenshot:
[image]

This screenshot is from linux mint 17 on firefox 38.0

Comment: I don't see what you mean on osx firefox. Can you provide screenshots/more info?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSS class #header-outer. **Remove the box-shadow lines**

**CSS**

```
  #header-outer 
  {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: visible!important;
  padding: 28px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 9998;
  /* REMOVE FOLLOWING box-shadow LINES or just replace this css code with yours */
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);*/
  }
```